# Flexslider shows 10px of previous image

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

Why does flexslider show 10px on the left from the previous image when it slides? What's the way to prevent that from happening?

See what I mean at http://nworks.nu/projects2013/sthlm/index.html

** I dont want to use overflow: hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do.. change `margin-left: -10px;` in `style.css`

```
.slides {
  max-height: 398px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```